# Join two data tables and use only one column from second dt

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

Let's say I have two data tables (dt1 and dt2), and I want to get dt3 using data tables. A,B,C,E,F,G,H are column names. dt1 key is column A, and dt2 key is column E. Data tables have different number of rows. I want to keep all the columns from DT1, and add only one column (H) from DT2 to the joined data table. Eventually, I will store this as DT1 (though I showed it as dt3 below).

How can I achieve it with data tables? I have an ugly solution with merge + data frames.

```
dt1 
A   B   C   
1   4   7   
2   5   8   
3   6   9   
2   20  21

dt2
E   F   G   H
1   10  13  16
3   12  15  18    
2   11  14  17


dt3
A   B   C   H
1   4   7   16
2   5   8   17
3   6   9   18
2   20  21  17
```

Comment: You want to do a left join to `dt1` and add a new column to it or you just want an outer join and create a new data set? If the first option is what you looking for, try `setkey(setDT(dt1), A) ; dt1[dt2, H := i.H]`

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. I want to keep all rows and columns from dt1. I just want to add a column from dt2. thanks

Comment: So why did you create `df3` then? Also, didn't my solution work for you? It should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Just ignore dt3 (was trying to make my example cleaner). Your solution works!! Thanks a lot... Just one question, how come we did not need to setkey for dt2? Is it because we use first column of dt2 to join by default?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though you can key `df2` by `E` for safety if you like.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to perform a *left join* to `df1` and add `H` column from `df2`, you can combine *binary join* with the *update by reference* operator (`:=`)

```
setkey(setDT(dt1), A) 
dt1[dt2, H := i.H]
```

See [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) and [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) for detailed explanation on how it works

---

With the devel version (v >= 1.9.5) we could make it even shorter by specifying the `key` within `setDT` (as pointed by @Arun)

```
setDT(dt1, key = "A")[dt2, H := i.H]
```

---

**Edit 24/7/2015**

You can now run a binary join using the new `on` parameter without setting keys

```
setDT(dt1)[dt2, H := i.H, on = c(A = "E")]
```

Comment: Could you please help me understand the use of "i.H"?

Comment: @Chris `i.` just tells data.table where to take the column from when you are doing a join. If we have `X[Y]` then the `Y` table is in `X`s `i` location. This is useful when both tables have columns with same names.

Comment: @DavidArenburg those links are broken. Is there anyway to only keep columns from dt1?

Comment: @HermanToothrot not sure what you mean. This solution already keeps only the columns from `dt1`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry I wasn't clear, I want to keep only columns from dt1 and no columns from dt2.

Comment: @HermanToothrot I understood you. When you run `setDT(dt1)[dt2, H := i.H, on = c(A = "E")]` you are only keeping the columns from `dt1` in `dt1`, while updating the `H` column from the `H` in `dt2`. Did you try the code? Perhaps post a new question as I don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` solution

```
setDT(dt1)[ , H := dt2$H[match(dt1$A , dt2$E)] , ]

#    A  B  C  H
# 1: 1  4  7 16
# 2: 2  5  8 17
# 3: 3  6  9 18
# 4: 2 20 21 17
```

another `dplyr` solution will be

```
left_join(x = dt1 , y = dt2 , by = c("A" = "E")) %>% 
select(one_of(c("A" , "B" , "C" , "H")))
```